# Code review requested: PowerShell executing multiple times against local PC instead of the desired remote PCs in $inventory

Tags: powershell, loops, variables, foreach

Stack Overflow community--greetings! Long time listener, first time caller. Also, this is my first foray into scripting, so don't beat me up too badly!

I've cobbled together a test script (from multiple websites) that I'm trying to use to identify some USB devices. It's currently testing against 4 machines on my local network, but will eventually reach out to thousands.

Long story short, my PS script doesn't appear to be using my **$inventory** variable when it runs, but instead runs the script against my local PC an equal amount of times as I have entries in the variable, and outputs the same (four times in this case). Surely I'm overlooking something simple, but hours of reading the same articles hasn't gotten me anywhere. I'm open to any suggestions!

```
$inventory = "pc1","pc2","pc3","pc4"
$target = "*usb*"

ForEach ($i in $inventory) {
Get-WmiObject win32_usbcontrollerdevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Where-Object {($_.Service -like $target)} | Sort SystemName,Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID | ft SystemName,Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID -auto 
}
```

Output (Please note, **MyLocalPC** listed below *should* be the four remote PCs listed above):

> SystemName   Manufacturer                   Description
>   DeviceID
>   ----------   ------------                   -----------                              --------
>   **MyLocalPC**   (Generic USB Audio)            USB Audio Device                         USB\VID_046D&PID_0A44&MI_00\7&73B6162&0&0000 
>   *(...output shortened for brevity...)*
>
> SystemName   Manufacturer                   Description
>   DeviceID
>   ----------   ------------                   -----------                              --------
>   **MyLocalPC**   (Generic USB Audio)            USB Audio Device                         USB\VID_046D&PID_0A44&MI_00\7&73B6162&0&0000 
>   *(...output shortened for brevity...)*
>
> SystemName   Manufacturer                   Description
>   DeviceID
>   ----------   ------------                   -----------                              --------
>   **MyLocalPC**   (Generic USB Audio)            USB Audio Device                         USB\VID_046D&PID_0A44&MI_00\7&73B6162&0&0000 
>   *(...output shortened for brevity...)*
>
> SystemName   Manufacturer                   Description
>   DeviceID
>   ----------   ------------                   -----------                              --------
>   **MyLocalPC**    (Generic USB Audio)            USB Audio Device                         USB\VID_046D&PID_0A44&MI_00\7&73B6162&0&0000 
>   *(...output shortened for brevity...)*

Another piece of information that may be of importance (?)--if I write the output of $i, it seems to be correct:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop> $inventory = "pc1","pc2","pc3","pc4"
$target = "*usb*"

ForEach ($i in $inventory) {Write-Output $i}
pc1
pc2
pc3
pc4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are simply running the same code based on the number of items in $inventory. You aren't actually inputting the computer names anywhere.

Add the `-ComputerName` parameter with the current item and it should work as expected:

```bsh
ForEach ($computer in $inventory) {
  Get-WmiObject win32_usbcontrollerdevice -ComputerName $computer | # pipe to other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks! While this *does* target the correct machines now, it still seems to run the script a total of 4 times--equal the amount of devices I have on the list. For instance, if I add a PC, it'll output a total of 5 times. I wouldn't imagine that's normal, but I don't really know any better either. Should there be a break of sorts? Have I inadvertently told my script to behave like this somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure if the odd behavior was resolved by my meddling or the reboot of my PC over the weekend, but all is well now. I appreciate the help!